# Multiline command.go in SciTE

Tags: editor, go, configure, scite

## The Short

This deals with SciTE and the go language in Windows (in particular, Windows 7). This is my first time using SciTE, so if there is another way to achieve my goal that is fine as well.

**Goal:** With one key press, compile, link, and execute the newly created binary.

## The Long

I want to setup the compile/link/excecute under the "go" command in SciTE. This may be slightly confusing as it is also for the [go language](http://golang.org). Here is what I have so far:

```
command.compile.*.go=8g $(FileNameExt)
command.build.*.go=8l -o $(FileName).exe $(FileName).8
command.go.*.go=$(FileName).exe
```

What I would like is to have something like:

```
command.go.*.go=\
8g $(FileNamExt)\
8l -o $(FileName).exe $(FileName).8\
$(FileName).exe
```

If this worked the way I intended it would compile the file, link it, and then run the executable. What happens is:

```
8g hello.go8l -o hello.exe hello.8hello.exe
```

When it should be:

```
8g hello.go
8l -o hello.exe hello.8
hello.exe
```

Where each line is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a batch script like so:

```
@echo off
if (%1 == "") (goto end)

set gofile=%1%
shift

8g %gofile%.go
8l -o %gofile%.exe %gofile%.8
%gofile%.exe

:end
```

The batch file can be anywhere, but let's say it's in 'C:\one\two\three\GO.bat' sans the quotes. In the SciTE property file change:

```
command.go.*.go=$(FileName).exe
```

to

```
command.go.*.go=C:\one\two\three\GO.bat $(FileName)
```

And when you hit F5 or click on "Go", it will compile, link, and execute the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have line continuation escapes with no spaces which is why it looks like that.

I don't know Windows, but in unix shells you can separate multiple commands with semicolons (or `&&` as peterSO mentions, which is more appropriate here).

You can still wrap, but realize that it's not going to consider the wrapping syntactically significant due, so add separation characters as appropriate.

Comment: In windows what I've found equivalent to the semi-colon is the double ampersands. However, SciTE doesn't seem to play nice. So while '8g %gofile%.go && 8l -o %gofile%.exe %gofile%.8 && %gofile%.exe' sans the quotes works in a batch file or in the command line, not so in SciTE.