# Why doesn't "8g foo.go -o foo.8" work for me in go language command line?

Tags: compilation, go

I'm trying to compile a hello-world app:

```
8g test1.go -o test1.8
```

Error:

```
open -o: No such file or directory
```

Irony here being that this works fine when I leave off -o:

```
8g test1.go
```

How do you specify an object filename to go command line compiler `8g`?

(8g version release.r60 9481)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `8g` is run without arguments, it prints something like this:

```
gc: usage: 8g [flags] file.go...
flags:
  ...
  -m print optimization decisions
  -o file specify output file
  -p assumed import path for this code
  ...
```

Notice that `[flags]` are positioned in front of `file.go`. This ordering needs to be respected when passing arguments. This is unlike `gcc` which accepts options and files in any order.

Comment: Sadly, this is rather arbitrary, and non-user friendly. gcc is the standard against which other command lines are going to either pass, or fail, in intuitive behaviour.  Did they think someone might want to compile a file named -foo and compile it to -foo.8?

Comment: @WarrenP, in fact, although a lot of programs now take the parameters in any order, there are still a lot that don't. The rule of thumb is to always give options before the files.

Comment: @WarrenP I do not know the precise reason for this convention, but it is used throughout Go. For example, the documentation for package `flag` says that "Flag parsing stops just before the first non-flag argument".

Comment: I second what @Shahbaz stated: being a long-time user of command-line applications, I wound't even think about placing an option (flag) argument after a non-option arguments.  The basic idea ("the common sense" for this case) is that the program name specifies an action then follows a set of modifiers to this action then follows a set of objects to carry that action upon; not just a random pile of stuff in arbitrary order for the command to grind through ;-)

Comment: Really? Maybe I'd like to do `8g foo.go -o fooX.8 bar.go -o barY.8`... This `grok -slowly theInfo` pattern makes sense when you get used to it, but so does GCC's behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

based on documentation

http://golangtutorials.blogspot.com/2011/05/checking-we-have-go-setup-right.html and

[Multiline command.go in SciTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503972/multiline-command-go-in-scite) and

http://sourcetree.wordpress.com/tag/go/

You can try

```
>8g test1.go 
>8l -o test1.8
>./8.out
```

Comment: Sorry, accidentally marked this one which points out what I already knew; which is that it works fine without -o in `8g`. Changed accept to answer which tells me exactly what I did wrong first.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler flags need to be specified before the list of input files, e.g.:

```
8g -o test1.8 test1.go
```

See http://golang.org/cmd/gc/